# gi.repository Gst problemas

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer

Estoy escribiendo un simple script para reproducir un archivo de audio con la librería Gst(gstreamer) de PyGobject, al ejecutar el script sale el siguiente error:

> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.705:  Trying to
>   dispose element pipeline, but it is in READY instead of the NULL
>   state. You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
>   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem
>   may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some
>   element.
>
> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.705:  Trying to
>   dispose element audio_source, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL
>   state. You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
>   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem
>   may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some
>   element.
>
> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.705:  Trying to
>   dispose element typefind, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL
>   state. You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
>   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem
>   may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some
>   element.
>
> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.705:  Trying to
>   dispose element decode, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL state.
>   You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before dropping
>   the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem may also
>   be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some element.
>
> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.706:  Trying to
>   dispose element convert, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL
>   state. You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
>   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem
>   may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some
>   element.
>
> (python3:31506): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 00:55:27.706:  Trying to
>   dispose element audio_sink, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL
>   state. You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
>   dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up. This problem
>   may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the application or some
>   element.

No consigo ninguna información al respecto, Aqui el Código de mi script:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst

class SimplePlayer:

    def __init__(self, path):

        self.path = path

        # Init Gst
        GObject.threads_init()
        Gst.init(None)

        #Create Pipeline
        self.pipeline = Gst.Pipeline('pipeline')

        #Create Elements for Pipeline
        self.source = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesrc', 'audio_source')
        self.decode = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decodebin', 'decode')
        self.audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert', 'convert')
        self.audio_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosink', 'audio_sink')

        #Configure Elemnts
        self.source.set_property('location', path)

        #Adding Elements to Pipeline
        self.pipeline.add(self.source)
        self.pipeline.add(self.decode)
        self.pipeline.add(self.audioconvert)
        self.pipeline.add(self.audio_sink)


        #Linking Elements
        self.source.link(self.decode)
        self.decode.link(self.audioconvert)
        self.audioconvert.link(self.audio_sink)

        # Finally Playing =D
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

        #I don't know well from here
        bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS)
        print(msg)

player = SimplePlayer('/home/user/Music/audio.mp3')
```

También si me pueden sugerir un tutorial para esta librería me seria muy útil. Gracias